# Unable to build Apache-ant-1.10.5

Tags: lfs

I'm trying to build BLFS 8.4
An error occurs when trying to download the runtime dependencies using the fetch.xml ant build script:
`bootstrap/bin/ant -f fetch.xml -Ddest=optional`

Error:

```
BUILD FAILED
/sources/BLFS/apache-ant-1.10.5/fetch.xml:212: The following error occurred while executing this line:
sources/BLFS/apache-ant-1.10.5/fetch.xml:122: Unable to resolve artifact: Missing:
--------
1) org.apache.ant:ant-antunit:jar:1.4

Try downloading the file manually from the project website.

Then, install it using the command:
mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=org.apache.ant -DartifactId=ant-antunit -Dversion=1.4 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file

Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there:

mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=org.apache.net -DartifactId=ant-antunit -Dversion=1.4 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[id]

Path to dependency:
1) org.apache.maven:super-pom:pom:2.0
2) org.apache.ant:ant-antunit:jar:1.4

----------
1 required artifact is missing.

for artifact:
org.apache.maven:super-pom:pom:2.0

from the specified remote repositories:
central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/)
```

Due to hardware limitations I am building BLFS 8.4 on the host machine. I'm using bash 5.0

Comment: Did you try what the error said?

Comment: @Nasir Riley I tried to download ant-antunit:jar:1.4 and install it with the command given but it didn't work. It says command not found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to build the version manually using the instructions from [Building Ant (Ant manual)](http://ant.apache.org/manual/install.html#buildingant)
combined with [Installation of Apache Ant (BLFS 8.4)](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/8.4/general/apache-ant.html) and got your error:

```
$ export JAVA_HOME=/path/to/my/java-11-openjdk-amd64
$ ./bootstrap.sh
$ bootstrap/bin/ant -f fetch.xml -Ddest=optional
...
[artifact:dependencies] Downloading: org/apache/ant/ant-antunit/1.4/ant-antunit-1.4.pom from repository central at http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/
[artifact:dependencies] Error transferring file: Server returned HTTP response code: 501 for URL: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/ant/ant-antunit/1.4/ant-antunit-1.4.pom
[artifact:dependencies] [WARNING] Unable to get resource 'org.apache.ant:ant-antunit:pom:1.4' from repository central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/): Error transferring file: Server returned HTTP response code: 501 for URL: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/ant/ant-antunit/1.4/ant-antunit-1.4.pom
[artifact:dependencies] Downloading: org/apache/ant/ant-antunit/1.4/ant-antunit-1.4.jar from repository central at http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/
[artifact:dependencies] Error transferring file: Server returned HTTP response code: 501 for URL: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/ant/ant-antunit/1.4/ant-antunit-1.4.jar
[artifact:dependencies] [WARNING] Unable to get resource 'org.apache.ant:ant-antunit:jar:1.4' from repository central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/): Error transferring file: Server returned HTTP response code: 501 for URL: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/ant/ant-antunit/1.4/ant-antunit-1.4.jar
[artifact:dependencies] An error has occurred while processing the Maven artifact tasks.
...
```

If you open http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/ant/ant-antunit/1.4/ant-antunit-1.4.pom you'll see that https is required.

#### Solution

Edit `./lib/libraries.properties` and change the `m2.repo` URL from `http` to `https` (line 29)

```
# Repository to use by default for fetching dependencies.
m2.repo=https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/
```

and run

```
bootstrap/bin/ant -f fetch.xml -Ddest=optional
```

again.